# Get week over week data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
CREATE TABLE messages  ( 
id          int(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
messagetext text NOT NULL,
created_at  timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

)

What I would like to do is to get two weeks of data, the current week and the previous week, ordered by days. For example how many messages were created on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday,Wednesday.... for this week and the last week.

I do have a query as follows

```
SELECT
    COUNT(id) AS 'Count' 
FROM
    'messages'
WHERE
    (WEEK(created_at) = WEEK(NOW())) 
GROUP BY
    WEEKDAY(created_at) 
ORDER BY
    week(created_at) ASC,
    weekday(created_at) ASC
```

but I don't know how to sort it day wise. For example the query above will list me how many did i get today or yesterday but that is not what what I want. What I would like to have is to get the count day wise as well as week wise.

Here is what I would like to have 
[image]

Please let me know if i clear enough with the situation that I am facing.

**Update:**
For more information , please see Juan's question below

If the current days are less that 14 days , in that case, the script should return the count for the days that are in the previous week , not the week before the previous week. Here is how Juan explained (imagine today is friday. if you count 14 day back you get this week monday to friday. previous week monday to sunday... and prev prev week friday to sunday. And not sure if that is the result you want)

With Regards

Gagan

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry ? Can you please be more specific ?

Comment: Please include db schema, sample data and desire output. please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
     And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza let me know how you would like to see the desired output ? as an image ? or as a table ? Please confirm. - thanks

Comment: table is always better because you can copy/paste. This may help  http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: See why we need sample data and desire output. I give you a total different answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional `SUM`

```
SELECT week(created_at) week_id,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 0, 1, 0) ) as monday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 1, 1, 0) ) as tuesday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 2, 1, 0) ) as wednesday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 3, 1, 0) ) as thursday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 4, 1, 0) ) as friday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 5, 1, 0) ) as saturday,
       SUM( IF(weekday(created_at) = 6, 1, 0) ) as sunday
FROM  'messages'
WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
  AND (      week_id = WEEK( NOW() ) 
         OR  week_id = WEEK( DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
      )
GROUP BY
    week_id
ORDER BY
    week_id
```

Comment: I am getting this error : [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.26-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
for the right syntax to use near 'weekday(created_at) = 0, 1, 0) as monday,
       SUM(IF weekday(created_at) = 1' at line 2

Comment: miss some parethesis, try again

Comment: probably need some tunning to return exactly last two week. But using `weekday()` wont use index, that is why I didnt use it on second version. Also in your question you didnt specify what happen if you run the query in WED. In this one you will show all 14 days. but in three different weeks.

Comment: yeah it did work.. but I am not sure what you said in your previous comment. Especially the last part ..

Comment: imagine today is friday. if you count 14 day back you get this week monday to friday. previous week monday to sunday... and prev prev week friday to sunday. And not sure if that is the result you want

Comment: Is there a way , I can circumvent that ?

Comment: Check now. I hope if you have index on date, first check will use index. Try using `explain plan` otherwise just use the second part.

Comment: @Juan don't you want to use a date to avoid losing the first part of the starting day? And this (forgive any bad MySQL syntax) would just go back to the correct Monday start date without unnecessarily widening the range: `created_at >= current_date - interval (weekday(current_date) + 6) % 7 + 7 day`

Answer (score 0):

Im going to send a big guess. But did you try something like this?

```
SELECT
    week(created_at) week_id,
    weekday(created_at) weekday_id,
    COUNT(id) AS 'Count' 
FROM
    'messages'
WHERE
      week_id = WEEK( NOW() ) 
  OR  week_id = WEEK( DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) )
GROUP BY
    week_id, weekday_id 
ORDER BY
    week_id, weekday_id
```